# How do I find drivers for Sony Vaio after fresh Windows install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Hoping someone can help - apologies if this is the wrong community to ask this in!

My Vaio VPCEE2E1E(1W) (Windows 7) has been fine but started displaying a message saying the hard drive had developed a fault, and advised to backup files and not use it if possible.

So I backed-up everything I need and wrote recovery disks.
I managed to find a new hard drive and fitted it.
I have an MSDN subscription so I tried to install windows from that but the disk obviously wasn't bootable.
I have a bootable version of Vista so I installed that, then installed a Windows 7 update.

But, most of the devices don't work.
It doesn't recognise its own network port or wireless adapter and even the DVD drive isn't visible from Explorer although I can run stuff from the "Start > Run" option.

At one point while trying to read a DVD it even developed a BSD error! I didn't get time to read it before the computer reset.

I have looked on the Sony website but the .COM site doesn't support my model; it says use the European site which doesn't have all the drivers I need, just a SATA driver and a few others.

What should I have done? I can easily "redo from start" if I just know what steps to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Ethernet and WLAN drivers on that site by clicking `Show all downloads`. The DVD drive would probably use the SATA driver.

IMO, you should start from scratch by performing a clean installing Windows 7 which may have drivers which will work with your hardware. If you do not have the disc, but do have a valid key, you can download your version and create a bootable DVD for installation.

[Download the appropriate Windows 7 .ISO file which includes Service Pack 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/cannot-find-digital-river-download-site/66a8439b-0d16-4b70-92f7-1c8486a46ebf)
(Note: must match what your product key version is for)

Comment: I have a valid key for Win7 "Upgrade" but not the key for the original pre-installed Win7; they are both Home Premium edition. I guess I could give that a go, thanks!

Comment: Update: it didn't work. Win 7 doesn't have the drivers and I can't copy the drivers on or download because no devices are recognised. Give up - will probably buy another laptop (NOT a Sony Vaio).